# Log in then subscribe, subscribe then log in, or something else?

Tags: website-design, mobile-web

I have a paid SaaS progressive Web app whose core functionality involves integration with Facebook. I'm primarily targeting mobile devices. New users will have to choose, and pay for, a subscription plan before being allowed access to the application's core functionality.

1. User purchases a subscription using the Stripe checkout page
2. Stripe redirects user back to application and informs application backend of the new subscription.

My question is, should the user be asked to log in to Facebook before they subscribe, or after?

It seems to me that, all things considered, it's better to have the subscription come after login. I can pass the user's app-specific Facebook ID to Stripe and thereby associate the user's Facebook profile with their subscription.

Comment: Can a user pay for a subscription and then associate it with multiple Facebook accounts (thinking of the Apple One subscription model)? Or is it always one to one?

Answer (score 1):

If they're only going to be signing in with FaceBook it makes sense to have them sign in first. As a user I would be thinking "how is everything going to be linked if they're asking me to pay first". That's just my opinion though, your best bet is to get some input from your target demographic. You can even ask your friends and family what they would prefer, if after asking a few people they're all giving the same answer then that's probably the better option.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you require facebook access and they lose their facebook access they will lose the ability to engage your app.

If you manage the initial access yourself you can control engagement without requiring facebook to be online, and perhaps offer additional services.